# How can you find the zeroes of a function with 1 point of the function and 2 points of the derivative of that function?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives

I'm trying to figure out this question, that states $3$ points, and then to find the zeroes of a quadratic function. However, the function itself is not stated. Basically this is how it goes $f(0) = x$. Then I am given $2$ points of the derivative of the function, $f'(x_1) = y_1, f'(x_2) = y_2$.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but I'm basically first finding the gradient of the derivative function, since if the function is quadratic, then it's derivative should be linear. I take $\frac{y_2 - y_1 }{ x_2 - x_1}$. Then solve for the $y$ intercept. Then I just reverse the derivation to get the final function, and solve for the zeroes. Is this the correct way of doing it? Or is there some other methodology?

Comment: Just edited your post to add some MathJax : you can take a look by attempting to edit this question . Drop by the [Beginner's tutorial for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) for drafting your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method will work. Knowing the equation of the (linear) derivative means you know everything about the quadratic except the constant term.

Alternatively, write the quadratic as $ax^2 + bx + c$ and use the data in the question to write three equations in the three unknown coefficients.

The methods are essentially equivalent. The second is somewhat more general, and does not require the nice geometric insight of the first.

Comment: I did forget to mention specifically that I am give f(0), which means that I am given the constant*. So I think it works. Thanks for the insight!